# How to test if variable exists in nested list and append it to that list in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Lets say for example i have a list called List1 which also contains two other lists (i.e nested list in python)

List1 = [['A'],['B']]

Then i have another list list called List2

List2 = ['A']

How do i iterate through the values of List1 and then check if List1 contains the value of List2 and append The value in List2 to index 0 in List1 which happens to be ['A']

This is what i've tried so far with enumerate but when i print List1 i keep on getting the same value [['A'],['B']]

```
List1  = [['A'],['B']]
List2 = ['A']

for idx, i in enumerate(List1):
    if List2 in i:
        List1.append(idx[i])

print(List1)
```

i want the result to be [['A','B'],['B']]

EDIT: i finally solved it and got the result i wanted

```
List1  = [['A'],['B']]
List2 = ['A']

for idx, i in enumerate(List1):
    if List2 in List1:
        List1[idx].append(List2[idx])

print(List1)
```

Comment: When does your second `B` come from? Your question seems to imply there'd be an extra `A`, instead?

Comment: Look at the types of your variables. `list2` is a list, `i` is a list. So the condition is never fulfilled. Anyway, you would get an TypeError in the next line.

Comment: "then check if List1 contains the value of List2". Do you mean "value of List2", or "value in List2". Because you use the latter in the next half of the sentence, but saying the first ("value of") means you want to compare the full lists.

Comment: oh i think i meant the value in List2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than just write some code and tell you exactly how to solve this problem, I'll say that using the python debugger would be a big help to show you exactly what your code is doing.

First, you can manually set a breakpoint in your code by adding `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` as follows:

```
List1  = [['A'],['B']]
List2 = ['A']

import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
for idx, i in enumerate(List1):
    if List2 in i:
        List1.append(idx[i])

print(List1)
```

Now, run your code:

```
$ python /tmp/t.py
> /tmp/t.py(5)<module>()
-> for idx, i in enumerate(List1):
(Pdb)
```

Your code executed up to the breakpoint and stopped.  Take a look around.  the `p` or `print` command shows you the contents of variables:

```
(Pdb) p List1
[['A'], ['B']]
(Pdb) p List2
['A']
(Pdb) p List1[0]
['A']
(Pdb)
```

OK, everything looks good so far, now use the `n` or `next` command to step to the next line of code:

```
(Pdb) n
> /tmp/t.py(6)<module>()
-> if List2 in i:
(Pdb) p idx
0
(Pdb) p i
['A']
```

OK, this looks like what we expected.  Sometimes I forget what the code around the current line looks like, that's when I use the `l` or `list` command:

```
(Pdb) list
  1     List1  = [['A'],['B']]
  2     List2 = ['A']
  3     
  4     import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
  5     for idx, i in enumerate(List1):
  6  ->     if List2 in i:
  7             List1.append(idx[i])
  8     
  9     print(List1)
[EOF]
```

Use `n` again to go to the next line of code:

```
> /tmp/t.py(5)<module>()
-> for idx, i in enumerate(List1):
(Pdb)
```

It started at the next iteration of the for loop!  Were you expecting this to execute line 7 next? Why didn't it?

Use `q` or `quit` to exit the debugger, then let's start over and go back to line 6 and then evaluate the expression in the debugger:

```
(Pdb) q
... 
bdb.BdbQuit
$ python /tmp/t.py
> /tmp/t.py(5)<module>()
-> for idx, i in enumerate(List1):
(Pdb) n
> /tmp/t.py(6)<module>()
-> if List2 in i:
(Pdb) p List2
['A']
(Pdb) p i
['A']
(Pdb) p List2 in i
False
```

Does that surprise you?  The issue you're having is that it is looking for an array containing 'A' in the list.

```
(Pdb) p ['A'] in i
False
```

For that to be true `i` would have to look like this:

```
(Pdb) p ['A'] in [['A']]
True
```

What you really wanted to ask was:

```
(Pdb) p 'A' in i
True
```

I hope that helps you debug your code!

- Note that I had to fix several typos to run your example.  Check your code to make sure it runs before posting your question next time.

Comment: Thanks i initially got the Type error that @Daniel said i would get but i was able to fix it though, also nice work for showing me the step by step process to debug the code it really helped me learn how to debug python codes cuz i didn't know how to use the eclipse pydev debugger

Comment: @danidee, using the debugger is a really valuable skill, welcome to the next level!